# HTML: "<a href="#xyz">" (on "/dir/test.php") links to "/#xyz" and not to "test.php/#xyz"?

Tags: html, anchor, document-root

This link: `<a href="#">link</a>` on `/dir/test.php` links to `/#` and not to `test.php/#xyz`.
What's wrong?

### A bit more specific:

on my page `http://mywebsite.com/medicine/test.php" there is a link:

```
<a href="#neu"><img src="/img/n1.png"></a>
```

and further down there is:

```
<h4 id="neu"><img src="/img/n1.png">Neuro</h4>
```

Even hovering over the link points to `mywebsite.com/#neu`.
Why? And how can I fix that (without having to use absolute addresssing)?

### Update

since removing a `<base >` tag, it has fixed the problem (thanks to @freejosh).

Comment: I can think of at least two completely different things that could cause that effect. You need to give us [more information](http://sscce.org/) about your code.

Comment: Do you have a [`<base>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) on the page?

Comment: @freejosh yes, I have a base tag (with mywebsite.com) **I have removed it and it works!** THANKS.